# Relational database design : duplicate attributes in tables for report

Tags: database-design

I am designing a relational database mainly for reporting. There are two reports :

- **car fleet** ( the customer wants to see the current state of its car : workshop or running, mileage, car manufacturer,..)
- **take over report**  (the customer wants to see the details when his car was handed over to a workshop : date of delivery, quanity of gas which is in the car, date of return, name of workshop, owner of the car).

The image depicts what attributes must be shown in the car takeover report and the car fleet report.

I was thinking to design the car fleet and car takeover tables as close as the generated reports but then lots of attributes are redundant in my tables.

Can someone tell me whether my database design is still acceptable for my usecase?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How often are the reports generated: a few times a month, a few times a day, a few times a minute? None of these warrant keeping a persistent copy of the report data. This redundant data is not just a waste of space, it severely complicates the DML to keep the data accurate and up to date and greatly increases the probability of errors creeping into the data.

What you *can* have are views named `car_takeover_report` and `car_fleet` which provide the data as seen in the diagram. This gives the report generator the latest data it needs in the format it needs without actually duplicating the data in a redundant way.

You also need a table to contain the current state of each car. The table `car_takeover_report` seems to be most of what is needed, just remove `mileage`, `car_owner` and `car_maker` as these are available in a join with the `car` table.

```
create table Company(
  ID      int   auto_increment primary key,
  Name    varchar()  not null,
  Street  varchar()  not null,
  City    varchar()  not null
);

create table Car(
  ID      int   auto_increment primary key,
  Mileage int  not null,
  OwnerID int   not null references Company( ID ),
  Make    varchar()  not null -- Really should be FK to mfgs table
);

create table CarStatus(
  ID      int not null primary key, -- one to one to Car table
  EffDate date not null,
  ReturnDate date,
  Fuel    int,
  Workshop varchar()   -- Really should be FK to Workshops table
);

create view CarTakeoverReport as
  select  s.EffDate as date_of_takeover, s.ReturnDate as date_of_return,
          c.Mileage, c.OwnerID as owner, s.Fuel as quantity_of_gas,
          c.Make as car_maker, s.Workshop
    from  Car       c
    left  join CarStatus s
      on  s.ID = c.ID;

create view CarFleet as
  select  ...;
```

Comment: Thanks for your good answer ! very much appreciated !  The reports are generated daily. I will stick on your solution